# Only load CodeIgniter Default Controller Rest of things not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, configuration, config

I have one site in .net and hosted in to first.com, and I make a subfolder to the `first.com/mysite`

and hosted as a codeingniter.

That folder not contain .htaccess file, only in root folder contain (first.com)

the config file contain below code

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://first.com/mysite/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

In my route file contain

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'products/integration';
$route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
```

But only load default control rest of the controller functions are not working.

Comment: check the size of the letters in paths

Comment: add the code of how your controller looks like. as well add the controller file path

Comment: Check your controller name controller name start with a Capital letter

Comment: have you tried http://yourdmain/index.php/controller url

Answer (score 0):

I am added new htaccess file to the new CI Folder.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

Now it's worked.